# Need advice with Bootpag pagination plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I'm currently trying to implement a bootpag pagination plugin. The original plugin can be found on [Botmonster's website](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#.VxoQoaiLSUk).
My issue is that I want this plugin to page through an unordered list, like the one I'm trying to create on jsfiddle. See [my attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/autimatrix66/h31j5t4y/2/).

Sample:

```
$('.test-pagination li').slice(4).hide();

$('.pagination-bootpag').bootpag({
    total: Math.ceil($('.news-pagination li').length / 4), // total pages
    page: 1, // default page
    maxVisible: 3, // visible pagination
    leaps: true, // next/prev leaps through maxVisible
    first: 'First page',
    last: 'Last page'
}).on("page", function () {
        $('.test-pagination li').hide();
        $('.test-pagination li').slice((page - 1) * 4, (page * 4)).show();
});
```

Four list elements are supposed to be displayed per page. Sadly, the pagination isn't shown in the fiddle, thus I can't get it paginate through the elements.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you open debugger on the same fiddle you shared you will know the reason.
Here is the error -

Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

The only good solution for this, try uploading jquery.bootpag.min.js on your own server or any other popular cdn and then include it in your html file.